# Sound from both headset and speaker

Tags: 12.04, sound

This is a common problem, i know but when i plug in my headset the sound keeps coming out of the speakers. The pc model is Acer Aspire 5930. When i start the pc with the headset plugged in, the sound comes out right, but when I plug it in after i have turned it on the sound comes out everywhere. System is ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sound from headphones and from speakers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-headphones-and-from-speakers)

Answer (score 2):

I think your sound card is an Intel. if yes try the solution here.

### Original Solution

1. Go to [Realtek official site](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false), accept the disclaimer, then download the audio driver for linux/unix. You need to select version 3 for Kernel 3 or later.
2. Setup necessary tools to compile this driver.

   `sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make`
3. Extract the downloaded file, run `sudo ./install` file from a terminal after going to the extracted folder to compile the driver.
4. Read the `Readme.txt` file for more information.

I had a problem with Sound settings in Ubuntu 12.04. It fixed now

---

### Solution 2:

I have just found another solution:

*(It worked for me with Only S/PDIF profile, Sound from both headphone and speaker and not being able to switch profile)*

Install `alsa-hda-dkms` using these commands

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms
```

Reboot, And See the result!