# Left Hand Side Speaker not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

I am using Dell Inspiron Zino 300 with Atom processor and 1GB RAM. It came with Ubuntu 9.04 preinstalled. I have now installed Ubuntu 12.04 in place of it. Everything seems to be working fine except the sound.

I have two external speakers but sound is coming only out of the right speaker.

Any suggestions to work around this?

Comment: Check the cable connections? Check whether that speaker is working with windows

Comment: The speaker is working fine with windows. It was working fine in Ubuntu 9.04 too. The Sound Profile does not show analogue stereo at all. Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/150959/61218) for not being able to select profile. It worked for me

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years the day this unanswered question about EOL Ubuntu 12.04 was posted. VTC as `not reproducible`.