# No sound from internal speaker but headphones OK

Tags: 12.04, sound, xubuntu, headphones, speakers

**The problem:**
The system won't play sound on the internal speaker of the laptop, but only on the headphone. When I put the headphone jack half in and fiddle around with it, then it'll play even on the internal speakers (the system apparently believes, that the headphone are in). What should I do?

**The technical data:**
Laptop modell Medion Erazer X6815

```
$ sudo aplay -l | egrep ^card
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC269VB Digital [ALC269VB Digital]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
```

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

```
$ uname -a
Linux matatabisama-X6815 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I had this same problem in Ubuntu 12.04, [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/150959/61218) helped me to fix the problem.