# Both Speakers and Headphone are giving Sound. How to fix it?

Tags: 11.10, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound from both headphones and speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers)

I have tried many solutions but they are not working for me i have Hp Pavilion Dv6 -2150us 
I'm new on Ubuntu and linux . so I don't know how to give command so kindly explain each and every work about giving command please, it is a request .

Comment: Check this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers/150959#150959

Comment: kindly tell how to explain the "sudo ./install" my terminal gives error.

Comment: What errors ? give a comment below the answer there. I think, you need to make the `install` file executable. `sudo chmod 755 ./install` will do the job

Comment: i do not know how to go to extracted folder and where it is . and how to extract

Comment: Extract the folder's content in your home directory

Comment: there is nothing in the download folder . where it would be ?