# Headset not muting speakers

Tags: pulseaudio, headphones, speakers, audio-jack

Plugging in the headphones does not mute the laptops speakers, music does play out of the headphones but also continues to play out of the speakers as well.  `alsamixer`'s 'auto-mute mode' is already enabled.

when I look at the sound settings in, 'output devices' it only has 1 item in the list 'Speakers Built-in Audio'.  Yet when looking at 'PulseAudio Volume Control' under 'output devices' the 'Port' drop-down list has 2 options 'speakers' & 'headphones'.  Selecting 'headphones' from that list does mute the speakers.

Specs:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Asus K55A.404

`aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC270 Analog [ALC270 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: These Q&A (from earlier releases) may still help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers.

Comment: Thanks.  While I had tested all these solutions, none of them worked for me.  It turned out to be a hardware based issue.