# No sound after doing some steps found here on askUbuntu

Tags: 12.04, sound

[Sound from both headphones and speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers)

I did the steps in the first answer there, and when I rebooted there was no sound at all. 
In the settings it says dummy output.
What Shall I do now ?!
I do not want to follow anymore steps that will make the problem even worse.
    sudo apt-get install aptitude

```
sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
```

I ran those two commands and I got my sound back. But the problem of the headphones not muting the rear speakers still exists!!!
Can anyone help me with that?

Running Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
```

I ran those two commands and I got my sound back. But the problem of the headphones not muting the rear speakers still exists!!!
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I copied your modification in the question because the user used a answer instead edit their question.

Comment: @revnoise: the commands indeed are an **answer** to the question, the issue with non-muting headphones however is a different question, which would then be a dupe to the question linked above.

Comment: I tried all of the stuff in that link and non of them worked for me!!!