# How I can change audio playing device?

Tags: sound

So I have 2 playback devices: mine subwoofer system (Line In), and Headphones (Jack), but sound is playing to both, I mute line in, but sound still is going to both.

What to do?
Realtek Sound Card.

[image]

Comment: It depends on your hardware, for example - https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers . Identify your sound card -

Comment: my soundcard is realtek high definition audo, intel

Comment: realtek is a brand, use lshw to show the chip. The link I gave you is for one realtek chip set, may guide you.