# ALSA-Mixer.conf bug!

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

So I had a problem, sound was going through speakers and headphones - BOTH.
Found a guide in this answer:
[Sound from both headphones and speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers)

That I should put this code:

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m4-1 enable_msi=1
```

To the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file.
I did it, and now NO SOUND AT ALL. 
Both headphones and line in - does nothing

Sound settings tab shows up - Dummy output.

[image: Mine sound settings tab]

Any ideas?
[Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1689586)

Comment: Does not work.!

Comment: I recommend that you revert the changes that you made to each this state, i. e. remove the two lines from `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and reboot. That's what I'm going to answer once this question is reopened if someone notifies me.

Comment: To reopen voters: OP clearly needs to revert the changes that lead to this state (see my previous comment). I have no idea how the linked question is supposed to help here.

Comment: Recovering does not help at all. I deleted it first, when I got the error. But I fixed problem... by installing Kubuntu. But I still need to know, what caused this.