# No sound from notebook speakers while I can hear the sound in headphones

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, speakers

I can hear no sound in the speakers. When I attach headphones the sound is heard correctly. alsmixer shows no clues:

[image: alsamixer screenshot with not headphones attached]

(when I attach headphones speaker gets muted and sound-bar of headphones goes up to 100 - visible in real-time)

Again pavucontrol - Ubuntu volume control - seems OK:

[image: Ubuntu volume control (pavucontrol) shows sound played]

(when I attach headphones port changes to "Headphones (plugged in)" - visible in real-time and I hear the sound via headphones as expected)

There is one thing interesting in gnome-alsamixer though. However I have no idea how to rectify it. When launched from terminal it prints the following errors:

```
    pdebski@PaDeLT430s:~$ gnome-alsamixer

    ** (gnome-alsamixer:24782): WARNING **: gam_toggle_get_state (). No idea what to do for mixer element "Auto-Mute Mode"!

    ** (gnome-alsamixer:24782): WARNING **:         gam_toggle_get_state (). No idea what to do for mixer element "Loopback Mixing"!

    (gnome-alsamixer:24782): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 71 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

and shows speaker muted:

[image: GNOME ALSA Mixer shows speaker muted]

However un-muting speaker and sliding it to top does not help. Same for "Internal". Note that when I close and reopen gnome-alsamixer both Speaker and Internal sliders stay at the top position but no sound from internal speakers is heard.

What else can I do to hear the sound in the speakers?

Comment: please take a look at below link, I hope it help you.
[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers?rq=1)

Comment: @Generic - Could you please be more specific what exactly shall I try? The post https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers include a number of various threads and answers. Which one exactly do you mean?