Ubuntu 24.04 on Levono Thinkpad: Only *one* audio output device
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a Levono Thinkpad E16. With earlier versions of Ubuntu on different machines I would have two audio output devices to choose from: The internal laptop speaker and headphones.
Now I have only one device shown: "Headphones - Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller". With and without an actual headphone connected sound always plays through the laptop speaker. If I connect a headphone sound also plays through it. But I cannot silence the laptop speaker without silencing the headphone.
Is this a problem of Levono thinkpads or can I get back to a situation where I can choose between the laptop speaker and the actual headphone?
To make sure it's not a hardware problem I booted into Windows. There I can choose between laptop speaker and headphone.
I also think that I could listen to sound only on my headphone and not through the speaker for some time afte the first install of Ubuntu. Could a recent update of udev or clould-init have caused the problem?

You can try using pavucontrol, sudo apt install pavucontroland check different configuration in the program, it usually  helps.

I tested pavucontrol, but it didn't help. It shows the same output devices. Under "Configuration" I can change "Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller" from "off" to "Pro Audio". Three appear then as output devices, but they don't have any effect on my headphones.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/stop-sound-from-speakers-when-connecting-headphones start from buttom

After fixing your problem you might want to get easy effects

Tried many things, finally found a very simple solution: I booted into Windows, shut down instead of rebooting the system, and after few seconds rebooted the system into Ubunutu. Headphones and speakers are again independent and speakers shut down if I plug in my headphones.
I found the solution here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1784862&sid=d2d89e7974657d3ea5541747034878b0#p1784862
One important point: My problem started without visiting Windows and I booted into Windows only after the problem had appeared. The solution worked nevertheless.
